# 80s UK TV show with women piloting a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship

I'm looking for an 80's 'space opera'-type series that was shown on UK TV. It was more adult than a children's series. It was the same sort of show as Space 1999, but I think several years before.

What I can remember of it was a spaceship taking off from a base and traveling to another planet. It was predominantly driven by women. The spaceship was big, with a cylindrical hole in the middle. There were loads of women fighting, traveling to different places.

Comment: Was the show British, or just shown on British TV?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like Star Maidens to me. 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maidens
Some overlap with Space : 1999 in terms of design of sets and costumes I believe.

Comment: Some videos are available [here](http://www.oldfutures.com/VideoGallery.aspx?titleid=315). It certainly has a Space:1999 "feel". Rather than a space ship, the asker may be remembering an underground city (which appears to have an airy layout) of the planet Medusa. The planet was torn from its stellar system by a comet and came to the Solar System (similar to Space:1999).

Comment: No, that not it. Good effort though. I think it's been forgotten about. The ships were doughnut shaped, that was flattened at one side, at the rear. I remember seeing a couple of episodes. I remember the ship rising out of a base, and traveling into space. The shot was used quite often. Early 80's.

Comment: http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2323/2112295416_5029ab816e.jpg

Answer (score 3):

[Space 1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%3a_1999) was a [Gerry Anderson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson) classic, aired between 1975 and 1977.

Before that was the 1970 series **[UFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_%28TV_series%29)**, my guess is that this series matches your criteria:

- Space 1999 style: yes, also by Gerry Anderson.
- before Space 1999: yes, by 5 - 7 years.
- spaceship with women: yes, if [grey suits and **purple wigs**](http://digilander.libero.it/guido_1953/pics/shado-3/ufo-gallery-1-moonbase.htm) look familiar
- spaceships with holes: this one I'm not sure about.

Do these links ring a bell?

Comment: Good try, but everybody and their granny knows about UFO and Space:1999. Both of these were children's programs, this was on late at night on STV/ITV in the UK.

Comment: @scope_creep No need to be snide in your responses.